# UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication middleware not working when self hosted

Tags: openid-connect, middleware, global-asax, webapi

I have a WebAPI that was hosted on IIS and I am attempting to move it into Service Fabric. Everything is working, except for my OpenIdConnect middleware. The redirect to the auth provider never happens. I have it setup to only redirect the user when they hit certain routes with a MapWhen

```
 app.MapWhen(owinContext =>
        {
            if (owinContext.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().StartsWith("/someroute))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }, adApp => adApp.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
```

I can debug into the MapWhen and I see it is returning true, but instead of a redirect nothing happens. Any ideas what could cause the redirect to fail? Is this middleware compatible with a self hosted app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the middleware and using Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.OAuth2Client to initiate a redirect server side instead.

The OpenIdConnect Owin middleware is meant to be used to secure MVC pages. When I removed the MVC routes from my app to go self hosted I beleive that is what broke it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a new project you should avoid UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication and use AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnect instead.

You can see that being mentioned like [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectAppBuilderExtensions.cs):

[Obsolete("UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication is obsolete. Configure OpenIdConnect authentication with AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnect in ConfigureServices. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=845470 for more details.", error: true)]

Also, I doubt you should put it inside MapWhen.

Comment: I ended up removing the middleware and using Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.OAuth2Client to initiate a redirect server side instead.  The heart of the issue is that I am doing an oauth handshake from the server for my angular app, and the server side middleware is meant to be used to protect MVC routes, the maphwhen was a hacky way of doing it.